# Execute a php script with F5 key in Vim

Tags: vim

I want to save and execute a script that's written in php with just pressing F5 key in vim.

So I added this line to .vimrc file :

```
:map <F5> :w<CR> :!php<CR>
```

But it doesn't work !

How can I do that's purpose with editing .vimrc file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those work for me (for `F3`):

```
autocmd  FileType  php nnoremap  <F3> <Esc>:w!<CR>:!php %<CR>
autocmd  FileType  php inoremap  <F3> <Esc><Esc>:w!<CR>:!php %<CR>i<Right>
```

Comment: autocmd  FileType  php nnoremap  <F5> <Esc>:w!<CR>:!php %<CR>
it works thanks !

Comment: @ali One is for `insert` another is for `normal` modes